# Utilise 100% GPU resource for YOLO v3 detection using single python script

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gpu, yolo

My System Configuration : I’m working on a Yolov3 model with GeForce RTX 2080 Ti GPU with 11 GB GPU memory and Intel(R) Core™ i9-9900KF CPU with 6 core and 64GB of RAM.

When i inference on images, my average FPS is between 35 FPS and GPU utilization is 1128MiB(~1GB out of 11GB). I use opencv and load the yolo on the GPU

I am able to increase the volume of image inference by running the same setup in 6 instances and I am able to achieve 210 FPS and GPU utilisation is 6760MiB(~6GB out of 11GB). However this method requires me to separate the images and feed non duplicate entries to each of the 6 instances.

How do I run a single instance that utilises the full GPU so I can extract the best FPS from all the 11 GB of GPU.

This will help me to feed the images from multiple sources to a single instances therefore reducing the need for me to split and assign to different instances.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: first script where inf is happening - 

def image_detect(image):
        image_path = image
        image, height, width, channels = load_image(image)
        blob, outputs = detect_objects(image, model, output_layers)
        boxes, confs, class_ids = get_box_dimensions(outputs, height, width)
        num = draw_labels(boxes, confs, class_ids, classes)
        print(image_path,num,t2)
        os.system("echo "+str(t)+","+str(image_path)+","+str(num)+",s1,"+str(t2)+" >> Inf_New_all_2.txt")
        #exec('try:pathlib.Path(image_path).unlink()\nexcept:pass')
        return num

Comment: calling inf script in while loop- 

import yolo_count1
import glob

paths=glob.glob("images1/*.jpg")

for path in paths:
 yolo_count1.image_detect(path)